# How to bundle .ts and .js files build in one file using rollup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I am trying to make a UI library that contained code in .jsx , now I want to make the new components in typescript (.tsx), is there a way to bundle my code in one file after running the build command.

My rollup config

```js
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import { DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS } from "@babel/core";

export default [
  {
    input: "./src/index.js",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
      },
      {
        file: "dist/index.es.js",
        format: "es",
        exports: "named",
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      postcss({
        plugins: [],
        minimize: true,
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
        extensions: [
          ...DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS,
          ".ts",
          ".tsx"
        ],
        plugins: [
          [
            "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
            {
              removeImport: true,
              additionalLibraries: ["react-style-proptype"],
            },
          ],
          typescript({
            include: "src/**/*.{js,ts}"
          })
        ],
      }),
      external(),
      resolve(),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "./src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
      },
      {
        file: "dist/index.es.js",
        format: "es",
        exports: "named",
      }
    ],
    plugins: [typescript()]
  }
];
```

my tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES2016",
"module": "ES2020",
"moduleResolution": "node",                     
"allowJs": true,
"noEmitOnError": true,
"jsx": "react",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"lib": ["ES2015"],                            
"strict": true,  
"esModuleInterop": false,                 
"outDir": "./dist",
"rootDir": "./"
  }
  ,
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
  // "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "src/components/Tag/index.tsx"]

}
```

Current issues : The build file contains code only of my ts files

package being used to add ts support :  "rollup-plugin-typescript2"

build command : "build-lib": "rollup -c"